# Elasticsearch bool results are incorrect

Tags: elasticsearch, search

I have a search query using `elasticsearch`, and in some cases when I search for a `boolean` field, I can see that there are opposite of my search in results..

this is my search query :

```
[
   "sort" => [
     [
        "_score" => "desc"
     ]
   ]
  "size" => 50
  "from" => 0
  "terminate_after" => 100
  "query" => [
     "bool" => [
       "must" => [
          [
            "query_string" => [
               "query" => "sales*"
               "analyze_wildcard" => true
               "default_operator" => "AND"
               "boost" => 1
              ]
          ]
          [
            "bool" => [
              "should" => [
                 [
                    "match" => ["gender" => 0]
                 ]
              ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
      "must_not" => []
    ]
  ]
]
```

for example, I have 50 results per page, and I see 40 number of my results has the `gender = 0` but 10 of them has `gender = 1`, I try with `term queries` but it didn't worked as I expected.. I don't want any gender with the value of 1.

in elasticsearch documents I couldn't find anything about my issue, if anyone has any doc or solution let me know..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after some changes on my elastic search array I tried `filter search` for my exact values, and now it works as I expected.

this is my code now:

```
[
  "sort" => [
    [
       "_score" => "desc"
    ]
  ]
  "size" => 50
  "from" => 100
  "terminate_after" => 100
  "query" => [
    "bool" => [
      "must" => [
        [
          "query_string" => [
            "query" => "sales*"
            "analyze_wildcard" => true
            "default_operator" => "AND"
            "boost" => 1
           ]
         ]
       ]
       "filter" => [
          [
            "bool" => [
              "should" => [
                 [
                   "term" => ["gender" => 0]
                 ]
               ]
             ]
           ]
         ]
         "must_not" => []
       ]
    ]
 ]
```